# Why very first message from Azure bot framework is always slow

Tags: azure, botframework, bots, azure-bot-service

The very first message from Azure bot framework is always slow.

Is there any way to optimise it?

Is possible to identify the connectivity of the bot?(for each user)
So that I can handle it from the HTML part.

Comment: `The very first message from Azure bot framework is always slow. Is there any way to optimise it.` You can try to turn on "**Always on**" on **Application settings** blade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The very first message from Azure bot framework is always slow. Is there any way to optimise it?

As I mentioned in comment, you can navigate to your bot's service in the Azure Portal, and then trun on **Always on** on Application settings blade.

You can also refer to this FAQ of bot service: [“My bot is slow to respond to the first message it receives. How can I make it faster?”](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-general-problems?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#my-bot-is-slow-to-respond-to-the-first-message-it-receives-how-can-i-make-it-faster)

> Is possible to identify the connectivity of the bot?(for each user) So that I can handle it from the HTML part.

If you embed web chat in your website using `botchat.js`, to pass [user identity](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#user-identity), you can specify `user: { id: user_id, name: user_name }` while you initiate BotChat.

Besides, if you are using the supplied `<iframe>` code, you can pass user identity via querystring `userid`.

```
<iframe src='https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/{BotId_HERE}?s={YOUR_SECRET_HERE}&userid={Your_userid_HERE}' width="300px" height="450px"></iframe>
```